# Xcode swift3 пакеты и структура проекта

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mobile-development

Я Пишу программки под андроид на андроид студия и там можно все четко структурировать(т.е. создавать пакеты все аккуратно разложить). Сейчас дней 7 как изучаю ios swift  и пока не могу понять даже в больших проектах мне придется все классы и контроллеры держать в одной папки? Или я что то не понимаю? Просто во всех example-ах все содержатся в одной папке и я не нашел команды типа new package (folder)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете добавить новую группу без создания папки и с созданием папки. Для этого, после нажатия правой кнопкой мыши в меню выберите New Folder:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С другой стороны, второй пункт может быть New Group with Folder, тогда нужно будет выбрать его.

Появилось в Xcode относительно недавно, поэтому во многих даже не очень старых примерах, все может быть свалено в одну кучу. Да и в новых, если не структурировать, а создавать группы без папок.

Comment: Еще можно выделить нужные файлы и выбрать New Group from Selection